# Windows:What actually happens when Ctrl+C is pressed in windows explorer

Tags: python, windows, winapi, python-2.7, pywin32

I am designing a Copy/Paste Application for Windows os using Python.Now I want to a Register my application with hotkey for "Ctrl+V" So that when any one press "Ctrl+V" Paste is done through my application and not through windows default Copy/Paste application.But I don't know how to get the list of files path which are to be copied and also the path of Target window where paste is to be done.So I want to know what actually happens when someone presses Ctrl+C key in windows explorer

Comment: Why did you make your *entire* question boldface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When someone presses the Ctrl+C key in Explorer, Explorer calls `OleSetClipboard()` with an `IDataObject` containing various formats, which may include `CF_FILES`, `CFSTR_FILECONTENTS` and `CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST`.

Comment: and what happens when 'Ctrl+V' is pressed and how would i get the path of that window in which 'Ctrl+V' was pressed.One last question how would i recognize between 'Ctrl+C' and 'Ctrl+X'

Comment: When Ctrl+V is pressed, whatever it's pressed in opens the clipboard, looks at what data formats are there, and decides what to do with them. There's no global 'clipboard paste' hook that you can use to redirect the behaviour to your app. You could try looking at the `ICopyHook` interface and see if it offers what you're looking for although I doubt it does. To answer your last question, the `CFSTR_PREFERREDDROPEFFECT` format lets you distinguish between cut and copy.